# Compiz / Unity permission problem?

Tags: 12.04, unity, compiz, permissions

I have a big problem here.
So the problem in short: I can't change my background, and the Compiz Launcher won't save stuff I put there.

What happened before this happened you might ask?
Well I reinstalled Ubuntu from 13.04 to 12.04 LTS because it refused to let me login.

---

My setup: I have 3 HDD's

- One mounted on / (12.04 LTS)
- And one mounted on /home
- And Windows 7 C: I don't really use it. (only for Windows games
  that can't be played though wine)

---

I reinstalled Ubuntu Tons of times (and used it) so my /home/(user) is filled with configuration files of programs.

I also have my /home encrypted.

Why do I think it's a permission problem?
Because it seems I have no permission to change my background or save thing on Compiz Launcher.

Any kind of help would be much appreciated.
Thanks for reading.

Comment: Ok I think I fixed it myself here is how:

Answer (score -1):

you'll only get this problem when you have /home mounted some where in a other partition,

> **WARNING: this worked for ME this is how *I* fixed it, it doesn't mean it
>   works for YOU,
>     This won't break your OS but WILL remove all your config files
>
>   (unless you made a back-up)**

Back-up your web browser data (and other config files that you may have there)
Firefox:
Backup ~/.mozilla (a hidden folder with bookmarks and history and cookies of Firefox)

Chromium:
No idea (Some one add this please, I think "~/.config/chromium" please confirm)

chrome:
No idea (Some one add this please, I think "~/.config/google-chrome" please confirm)

then remove every .(name) folder in your or back them up somewhere.
Point is they can't be in /home/user/* (or further).